# what is the best way to check similarity between two persons?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I want to count unique perons in video.
I used Mean square error , Sift algorithm and pre-trained model (Deep_ranking)
https://github.com/USCDataScience/Image-Similarity-Deep-Ranking
to check similarity but I doesn't get good results.

Answer (score 1):

What is the best way to check similarity between persons is for you to decide, because it depends on your task.
But you may get interested in "person re-identification" problem.

https://github.com/bismex/Awesome-person-re-identification

Also you may want to try metric learning - approach, when you get feature vector for each sample (image, for example) using neural network (or other ML algorithm).
Usually you can just take neural network for classification (for example, VGG or ResNet), train it on N classes, where N is a number of persons in your dataset, and then take output from the layer before class predictions. So you get feature vectors for your images and then you can compute euclidean or other distance. Images with small distance probably can be from the same person, images with large distance - from different persons.
I personally tried this solution:

https://elib.dlr.de/116408/1/WACV2018.pdf

https://github.com/nwojke/cosine_metric_learning

Comment: Also you can like this simple solution: https://github.com/digitalbrain79/person-reid